# Laravel: redirecionar depois de logar

Tags: laravel, autenticação, redirecionamento

Pesoal, tudo bem?
Estou enviando um email para o cliente assim:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => env('APP_URL') .'/SobeDocsFiadorCadastrado/'. $fiador->id ])
Clique para iniciar
@endcomponent
```

Porém, o sistema obviamente pede as credenciais de login e depois de passá-las, eu preciso que o usuário seja direcionado para a rota que está no botão, mas ao invéz disso, ele vai pra home.

Aqui está o pedaço do código do LoginController que cuida disso:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
        $login = $credentials[$this->username()];
        $cpfCnpjHigienizado = str_replace('-', '', str_replace('/', '', (str_replace('.', '', $request->cpfCnpj))));
        $credenciais = User::where('cpfCnpj', '=', $cpfCnpjHigienizado)->first();
        if ($credenciais) { // Se já estiver cadastro, vai pra home
            Auth::login($credenciais);
            return redirect(route('SobeDocsFiador'))->withFiador($request->fiador);
            // return redirect(route('home'));
        } else {
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////// INICIO LOGIN NOS WS

-> a partir desse ponto, sei que o não é cadastrado e vai fazer outra coisa
```

Enfim, como faço para redirecionar para a URL que envio por email?
Já tentei um `return $request->all();` pra ver o que retorna depois do login ,mas o param `$fiador->id` não vem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Da uma olhada nesse link, acho que pode te ajudar](https://codeburst.io/learn-how-to-redirect-authenticated-users-to-corresponding-path-in-laravel-dd613e2f9e3)

Basicamente o `LoginController` tem um metodo `public function redirectTo()`, ai nele vc pode fazer uma validação usando uma query string tipo `next_uri`.

Comment: Muito bom mesmo Allan, obrigado!
Mas não é pelo role que quero redirecionar, mas por rota, por exemplo: Eu mandei um email para o usuário ir para a rota 'SobeDocsFiador'. Só que antes ele tem que se logar e então ser redirecionado pra essa rota. Só que não vai... ele cai na home

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi usando o método

```
compact('credenciais')
```

Agora ele pede o login e depois vai pra rota certa que é:

```
Route::get('SobeDocsFiadorCadastrado/{id}', 'DocumentoController@SobeDocsFiadorCadastrado')->name('SobeDocsFiadorCadastrado');
```